# How do I export default with two functions in JS React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { withTranslation } from 'react-i18next'

...

export default 
  withTranslation()
  connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Form);
```

Comment: Can you please add more information about your goal? Your post is a bit unclear

Comment: You can export an object {} with your two functions inside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:-

`export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(withTranslation(Form));`

OR

`export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(withTranslation()(Form));`

Depends on the implementation of your HOC and this is if the HOC was to be used for the Form component.

Comment: I did it !! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score -1):

When you want to export two or more variables, function, classes, etc. Just add the keyword export before its declaration. For example:

```
export const FRUITS = ['apple', 'banana'];
export function getRandomFruit = () => {
  return FRUITS[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
};
```

And when you imported it, just like this:

```
import { FRUITS, getRandomFruit } from './fruitController';
```